# Default UncaughtExceptionHandler not being called from nested thread

Tags: java, multithreading, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I've read through several examples of how to use an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to pass exceptions from a nested thread to a parent thread. Currently, my nested thread's `UncaughtExceptionHandler` catches exceptions as it should. I've set it to pass exceptions to the parent thread's default `UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(...)` method.

```
public void load() {

    // Create the nested thread
    final Thread loadingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff... throw an exception at some point
            throw new RuntimeException("Something has gone horribly wrong!");
            }
        }
    });

    // Set up a custom exception handler for the nested thread
    class LoadingThreadExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

        // The parent exception handler
        private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;

        // Constructor to get a handle on the parent's exception handler
        public void LoadingThreadExceptionHandler() {

            // Check if the parent thread has an exception handler
            if (Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() == null) {
                System.out.println("The default handler is null");
            }

            // Get the parent's default exception handler
            defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

            System.out.prinln("This is the nested thread's handler");

            // Pass it onto the parent's default exception handler
            defaultHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
    };

    // Set the custom exception handler on the loadingThread
    loadingThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new LoadingThreadExceptionHandler());

    // Start the thread
    loadingThread.start();

    return;
}
```

Running this produces the following output:

> This is the nested thread's handler

For whatever reason, the nested `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is called, but it doesn't seem to pass the exception to the parent thread's default `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, as nothing happens after that point. I did at one point suspect maybe the parent's default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` was null so, I added some logic in the constructor to check for this and print a message, but this doesn't seem to ever be the case. I've also attempted overriding the parent's default exception handler as well, although to no avail.

Am I missing something here? I cannot, for the life of me, understand why the parent's `uncaughtException(...)` method never seems to be called.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void LoadingThreadExceptionHandler()
```

This is not being called, because it's not the constructor. When you invoked `new LoadingThreadExceptionHandler()`, the no-arg default constructor (which is created by the compiler if no constructor exists) is invoked.

To fix it, it should be without a return type:

```
public LoadingThreadExceptionHandler()
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I made such an elementary mistake! Removing the return type did indeed make it work. Thank you!

Comment: @AnnaW I am glad that I could help. I think most IDEs would show a warning mentioning that the method name is identical to the class name.